# How to delete iCloud Key-Value Data

Tags: iphone, ios, sdk, icloud

I'm using the iCloud Key-Value Data storage solution, so I'm not working with documents (UIDocument).  I've got the syncing implemented, and it seems to work well.  However, I need to do some more detailed testing, now, and I can't figure out how to force delete the data on iCloud.

How can I delete data from my iCloud account for testing purposes?

I've tried this:

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setArray:[[NSArray alloc] init] forKey:@"iCloud_BG_KEY"];
```

I've also tried this:

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] setArray:nil forKey:@"iCloud_BG_KEY"];
```

As well as turning off iCloud Backup for my app (Settings > iCloud > Storage & Backup > Manage Storage > [my_backup_device] > Show All Apps > [my app]).

And of course, I'm deleting my app and rebuilding and running xcode.

How can I force delete of the iCloud files (again, for Key-Value data storage)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about

```
[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] removeObjectForKey:@"key"];
```

?

Comment: Wow, guess I should stop coding at 1:30 in the morning. Just before I saw your post, I figured out that setting it to an empty (but allocated) array would also work.  In either case (using the more appropriate "removeObjectForKey" or setting to empty array), I needed to call "synchronize" to force the update.  I wasn't waiting long enough.

Comment: @jimpic I also need to delete all the data stored on iCloud.Can you please tell what to write in key parameter.I  am not getting what should I write in key value to delete all data stored on iCloud.Please help.

Comment: @Gypsa use [[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] dictionaryRepresentation] and iterate through it, unsetting the keys contained.

Comment: @jimpic I do NSLog(@"[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] dictionaryRepresentation]=%@",[[NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore defaultStore] dictionaryRepresentation]); but the dictionary is empty.There are no data in it.What should I do now.

Comment: @Gypsa Find out how to iterate through a dictionary. A dictionary is not a string. If it really is empty, then there is no data on your iCloud.

Comment: There is a lot of data on my cloud but the dictionary is returning empty.

Comment: We are talking about the Key-Value store of iCloud, right? Not whole iCloud?

Comment: HI Jimpic, Can you please hele me. I want to sync Database on iCloud. If you have any Example Code. Thanks in Advance. Suresh